# Touch views from another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, view, scroll, xamarin

`OnScrollChanged` method fired multiple times.
I have used `Timer` for detect last scroll only.
How can I change my `TextView` from another `Thread`?

## Code

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   ...
}

public class UsefulScrollView : HorizontalScrollView
{ 
    ...

    private static System.Threading.Timer timer;

    protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            TimerCallback tcb = CheckStatus;
            timer = new Timer(tcb, null, 500, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            timer.Change(500, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }

    protected void CheckStatus(Object stateInfo)
    {
        TextView tv = linearLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(101);
        tv.Text = "abc" // error
    }
}
}
```

## Exception

```
ERROR: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

Comment: timer?  what do you need it for?

Comment: When I use scroll, method "OnScrollChanged" fired multiply time. I use Timer for detect LAST scroll only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't have `ScrollHelper` be static. It doesn't need to be. Then you can have a reference to it within your `UsefulScrollView` and `ScrollHelper` will be able to access fields from its enclosing class such as `linearLayout` and be able to edit the `TextView`. You'er right about trying to use `MainActivity.RunOnUiThread` but you may not have to seeing as all of it will be coming from the main thread anyway (through the `OnScrollChanged` method)

Comment: OK, but how I can detect last scroll in OnScrollChanged without timer? If ScrollHelper will be non-static, I must create ScrollHelper sh = new ScrollHelper() in OnScrollChanged method and my timers will be differents.

Comment: no, it can be created in the constructor of your `UsefulScrollView` and set as a field inside that class. Then you access it from `OnScrollChanged `.

Comment: I changed my code (see question). Class is non-static, but code doesn't work.

Comment: @user3707143 I haven't written in Xamarin before but I looked at the [docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/) for using `RunOnUiThread` and they seem to use it like `RunOnUiThread (() => tv.Text = "Method Complete");` rather than statically like you have: `MainActivity.RunOnUiThread`

Comment: I wrote RunOnUiThread instead of MainActivity.RunOnUiThread. Error:
Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'Android.App.Activity' via nested type 'ChartApp.MainActivity.UsefulScrollView'

Comment: Do you even need to use `RunOnUiThread `? Isn't is already on the main thread or is it something you have to do because of Xamarin?

Comment: This is another thread (tv.Text = "abc"). I don't know how I can change my TextView.

Comment: try using `tv.post (runnable)` from [here](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M:Android.Views.View.Post(System.Action)). I'm not sure what the syntax of Xamarin is, but there's the doc so you can work it out yourself. The issue you're having is that you need to be within an `Activity` or have an `Activity` to reference to use `RunOnUiThread ` and that seems tricky in this case for some reason. We can use the `TextView` instead and gain access to the mainthread through it instead using [View.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))